# jQuery checkbox get value and attribute and push to data ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have multiple, and I want to get the value, the attributes of each selected checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="access[]" id="configuration" value="configuration" data-text="Configuration"> Configuration
<input type="checkbox" name="access[]" id="department" value="department" data-text="Departments"> Departments
```

I want to get all selected checkbox and store it to an array and push it to ajax

```
var classids = checkboxes.map(function(){ return $(this).attr("id"); }).get();
var val      = checkboxes.map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get();
var datatext = checkboxes.map(function(){ return $(this).attr("data-text"); }).get();
```

How can I combine the three to make it one? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array of object, you could just map relevant properties you are looking for:

```
var arr = checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(){
  return {classids : this.id, val: this.value, datatext: this.dataset['text']}
}).get();
```